Prevent calling Observer
I have an observer to catch the event customer_save_after when user update the information. It works well. But somewhere in my code, I also have this
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById(1);

$this->customerRepository->save($customer);

to save customer information. And this also trigger to that observer. How can I control which will trigger that observer and which not?
So far, I find this solution

Declare new class Vendor/Module/Model/ObserverFlagManager.php

<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class ObserverFlagManager
{
    private $flags = [];

    public function setFlag(string $key, $value)
    {
        $this->flags[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function getFlag(string $key)
    {
        return $this->flags[$key] ?? null;
    }


    public function resetFlag(string $key)
    {
        unset($this->flags[$key]);
    }
}


Inject the Flag Manager into Your Classes and Observer

use Vendor\Module\Model\ObserverFlagManager;

public function __construct(
    ObserverFlagManager $observerFlagManager,
    // other dependencies
) {
    $this->observerFlagManager = $observerFlagManager;
    // Initialize other dependencies
}


Set and Check the Flag

$this->observerFlagManager->setFlag('suppress_customer_save_after_observer', true);

$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById(1);
$this->customerRepository->save($customer);

$this->observerFlagManager->resetFlag('suppress_customer_save_after_observer');

and in Observer
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->observerFlagManager->getFlag('suppress_customer_save_after_observer')) {
        return; // Skip observer execution
    }

    // Your observer logic here
}

Because I'm still new to Magento 2, could anyone help me check if this approach may raise any issues? I already implement this and so far, it works fine.
Thank you all

Your approach seems to be good. Another way of doing is if You can take a customer identity-based approach. Check for any custom fields that appear differently in customer responses. Validate these fields against your response to identify if any custom fields are missing the specific values you want to be consistent across the customer repository. Then, apply a check to see if this field exists in your current response. If it doesn’t, proceed with the customer repository save function otherwise, continue with your existing code.
For example
Set the customer custom attribute value in function you want to skip.
 $customer->setCustomAttribute('custom_field', 'default_value');

Now in your function check this attribute value and proceed.
$customFieldValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('custom_field');

// Check if the custom field exists and has a value
if (!$customFieldValue || $customFieldValue->getValue() === null) {
        //do you code here
}

